# How to handle layers on slider using LayerSlider?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I using LayerSlider to make carousel on my website. Now when I click to Prev/Next button, the slider move to the first layer automatically.

I want to custom my Javascript. Click next to get next layer, not get the first layer. Here is my code:

```
var sliderObject = lsjQuery("#layerslider_6").layerSlider({
        // height : __height,
        responsive: false,
        responsiveUnder: 1900,
        layersContainer: 1900,
        pauseOnHover: false,
        navStartStop: false,
        twoWaySlideshow: true,
        navButtons: false,
        // skin : 'fullwidth',
        showCircleTimer: false,
        cbInit: function (data) {
            matchSizeLayerElement();
        },
        cbAnimStart: function (data) {
            matchSizeLayerElement();
            // console.log('Animate Start' + (new Date().getTime() / 1000));
        },
        cbAnimStop: function (data) {
            matchSizeLayerElement();
            // console.log('Animate Stop' + (new Date().getTime() / 1000));
        },
        cbPrev      : function(data){
            console.log('Click Prev');
        },
        cbNext      : function(data){
            console.log('Click Next');
        },
    });

    lsjQuery("#layerslider_6").layerSlider('start');
```

I was searching more and more times, but I counln't any solutions.

Sorry for my bad English.

```
Each answers will become the God save my life!
```

Answer (score 1):

Check out the [API Methods](https://support.kreaturamedia.com/docs/layerslider/documentation.html#api-methods) section of the LayerSlider documentation, I believe it has the information you're looking for.

```
// moves to the layer after the current layer:
lsjQuery("#layerSlider_6").layerSlider('next'); 

// moves to the layer before the current layer:
lsjQuery("#layerSlider_6").layerSlider('prev'); 

// moves to the 4th layer (regardless of current layer):
lsjQuery("#layerSlider_6").layerSlider(4);
```

Comment: I tried to apply all APIs before, the slider will reset to the first layer, not next/prev layers. The website http://uniq-cosmetics.vn/en/demo

Comment: I'm not able to find the code on that page, can you create an example on jsFiddle that reproduces the issue so that it's easier to fix?